# access denied GVR SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality

I am trying to install a version of the GoogleVR SDK, however I get this message in unity after pressing the import button.

> Copying Temp/Export
>
> Package/59a575daa4f43d1468a5f9a51e1b1c2a/59177834662aa4ead89a6c07a4715165/asset to Assets/Plugins/x86_64/audioplugingvrunity.dll: Access is denied.

Comment: I do believe that audioplugingvrunity.dll is loaded when Unity Editor loads and when you click run. Close Unity, or restart it then try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

- Close Unity Completely
- Using the file browser, navigate to your projects: Assets\Plugins\
- Delete the x86_64 folder (The only thing in this folder was the
  previous audioplugingvrunity.dll)
- If you have x86_64.meta file, delete that too.
- Open up your unity project and re-import the package.